# How can I make a consistently transparent fade, disregarding what has been drawn below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

[image]]

In my code, I have a path that uses a custom fading that has been defined previously. It is supposed to fade the current scope's border, but, as you can see, that only happens when there is only one filling in place. When I overlay multiple fillings, their total opacity compounds and the border becomes less and less faded. How can I avoid that? I know that, in this example, the solution would be to simply change where the rectangles begin and end, but this is simply an exemplification, as I want to apply this concept to much more complicated figures, where calculating when to begin a filling to avoid this problem would be practically unfeasible. As a bonus question, how can I stop the blue filling affecting the red part and vice versa? Here's the code for the picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=my fading]
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (0.5,0.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (7.5,7.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (7.5,0.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (0.5,7.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[top color=transparent!0,bottom color=transparent!100] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (7.5,0);
            \shade[right color=transparent!0,left color=transparent!100] (0.5,7.5) rectangle (0,0.5);
            \shade[bottom color=transparent!0,top color=transparent!100] (0.5,7.5) rectangle (7.5,8);
            \shade[left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100] (7.5,0.5) rectangle (8,7.5);
            \fill[transparent!0] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (7.5,7.5);
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \clip (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
        \fill (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
        \path [scope fading=my fading, fit fading=false,fading transform={shift={(current bounding box.center)}}];
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,4);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,2);
        \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (8,1);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,0.5);
        \draw[->,thick,red] (1,5) -- (0.25,4.25);
        \draw[->,thick,red] (1,3) -- (0.25,2.25);
        \draw[->,thick,red] (1,2) -- (0.25,1.25);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome! Nice question! You need to put the stuff in a `transparency group`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=my fading]
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (0.5,0.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (7.5,7.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (7.5,0.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100] (0.5,7.5) circle (0.5);
            \shade[top color=transparent!0,bottom color=transparent!100] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (7.5,0);
            \shade[right color=transparent!0,left color=transparent!100] (0.5,7.5) rectangle (0,0.5);
            \shade[bottom color=transparent!0,top color=transparent!100] (0.5,7.5) rectangle (7.5,8);
            \shade[left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100] (7.5,0.5) rectangle (8,7.5);
            \fill[transparent!0] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (7.5,7.5);
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}% <- the % removes spurious space
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \clip (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
        \fill (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
        \path [scope fading=my fading, fit fading=false,
        fading transform={shift={(current bounding box.center)}}];
        \begin{scope}[transparency group]
         \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
         \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,4);
         \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,2);
         \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (8,1);
         \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (8,0.5);
         \draw[->,thick,red] (1,5) -- (0.25,4.25);
         \draw[->,thick,red] (1,3) -- (0.25,2.25);
         \draw[->,thick,red] (1,2) -- (0.25,1.25);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]